# How does Heroku display logs on git push?

Tags: git, heroku

Whenever I push to Heroku, I get a comprehensive set of logs:

```
-----> Node.js app detected

       PRO TIP: Specify a node version in package.json
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

-----> Defaulting to latest stable node: 0.10.32
-----> Downloading and installing node
-----> Restoring node_modules directory from cache
-----> Pruning cached dependencies not specified in package.json
-----> Node version changed since last build; rebuilding dependencies
```

This is coming from the output of `git push`, not their toolbelt.  How are they displaying this?  Is this some configuration on their git server?  Is the toolbelt hijacking the output?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but would it be worth having a look at the source code for the command line client? https://github.com/heroku/heroku